# subprocess.call makes unwanted action

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I run this function to make moving files finish before other script lines are read. When I move video files subprocess.call moves and plays the video.

I what to avoid playing. How can I do that. There is an option to send output to NULL. stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL. But it did not help.

```
    def move_files_while_script_waits(src, dest):
        try:
            for a_file in os.listdir(src):
                old_place = os.path.join(src, a_file)
                new_place = os.path.join(dest, a_file)
                subprocess.call(shutil.move(old_place, new_place),shell=True)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

Comment: Unless `shutil.move()` is a function that returns the string of the command to move files, then you're seemingly not passing the right arguments to `subprocess.call`. According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) it looks like you're meant to pass that function the string of the command you want to execute. So, what's probably happening is that you're calling the function `shutil.move()` over and over in a loop and so that's why you're not getting the output you expect.

Comment: What on earth do you think `subprocess.call` is doing here? You're not running a command at all. No video should every play based on this code.

Comment: @ShadowRanger You are wrong. It moves files perfectly well. And also moves the video files. But it plays video files. And that I need to avoid.

Comment: @LetzerWille: Ah, okay, I see what's happening. `shutil.move` returns the ultimate path to the file you moved to. You then invoke that as if it were a raw command in a shell, which likely means based on file associations, it launches a player when it ends in a video extension. Just replace `subprocess.call(shutil.move(old_place, new_place),shell=True)` with `shutil.move(old_place, new_place)` alone; that move the file and doesn't try to "run" the file.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, subprocess  makes the script wait until the files are moved.

Comment: @LetzerWille: No, it doesn't. `shutil.move` does not return until the files are moved (there's no backgrounding, it literally doesn't `return` until the new file exists and the old file is gone). All `subprocess.call` does is try to run a command equal to the final path where the files were moved to *after* the move is already complete. You're misunderstanding what `subprocess.call` is for (it's for running *external*, non-Python command line utilities); `shutil.move` is an internal Python API, and the fact that `subprocess.call` works at all is an artifact of Windows' approach to attaching...

Comment: ...file extensions to launcher programs which means you can "run" a file that is not an executable at all, and it gets interpreted as a request to launch it in the default handler program (so you ask it to run `C:\path\to\foo.avi`, it looks up the handler for `.avi` files, and launches said handler asking it to play `foo.avi`).

Comment: The only part I missed initially is that apparently `shutil.move` has a return value. I was expecting it to return `None`, having no useful thing to return, but it instead returns the resolved path to the target file, which on Windows, leads to the behavior you describe (on other OSes, it would only do something meaningful if the file moved was an actual executable, on Windows, it works for any file with an associated file handler).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need [**`shutil.move`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html), perhaps ?

Try this :

```
def move_files_while_script_waits(src, dest):
    try:
        for a_file in os.listdir(src):
            old_place = os.path.join(src, a_file)
            new_place = os.path.join(dest, a_file)
            subprocess.call(["powershell", "-Command", fr"mv {old_place} {new_place}"])

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I use windows 10 and get this error.  'mv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: In this case, you need Powershell. I updated my answer!

Comment: @abokey: This is needlessly delegating simple file moves (which Python can handle internally, and give more useful errors if it fails) to external utilities. The part to remove is the pointless `subprocess.call`, not the `shutil.move`. Doubling down on `subprocess.call` solutions to simple file movement is brittle, and often slower.

Answer (score 0):

```
subprocess.call(shutil.move(old_place, new_place),shell=True)
```

Is doing two things:

1. `shutil.move(old_place, new_place)` moves the file to the new location
2. `subprocess.call(..., shell=True)` on the return value of `shutil.move` (the path to the destination file) is likely recognizing specific file extensions for video files and launching them with the default handler application.

If you don't want to play the files, just get rid of `subprocess.call`, changing the line to:

```
shutil.move(old_place, new_place)
```

which will move the files on its own (it's not an external utility, so `subprocess` isn't needed to move the files at all), and not try to "invoke" them for the Windows definition of "running" video files.

Comment: subprocess makes the script to wait, until all files are moved. I am repeating myself just for others to see my comment.

Comment: @LetzerWille: It does not. `shutil.move` is already blocking. `subprocess.call` doesn't get invoked until `shutil.move` is *done* and the file is already moved. You're engaged in cargo cult programming; someone told you to use `subprocess.call` to wait until the task finishes (in contrast to `subprocess.Popen` that launches processes in the background without waiting for them to finish) and you thought they meant it worked for arbitrary Python tasks. It does not. `shutil.move` returns the path it moved the file to after it finishes, then you try to launch that path as an external program.

Comment: Windows then looks up the associated file handler and launches the handler program with the file as the argument, so when it's a video file, that means it launches a video player program. *Never* use `subprocess` (any API) unless the *intent* it to launch some external utility, it doesn't do anything useful with internal Python API calls.

Comment: @LetzerWille: In short, `subprocess.call` *is* the source of the "unwanted" action you mention. And the *only* action it's taking is to create that unwanted behavior. Aside from no longer launching these videos (and any other executables or files with registered handler programs), your code would behave *exactly* the same if you simplified it to just the `shutil.move` call (which, as I've said, is a blocking call; it does not return until the file is fully moved, you don't need to do anything to make it wait until the files are moved because you can't *not* wait without resorting to threads).

Comment: that makes sense. But I need moving files to finish and script to wait until files are moved. So may be a loop while True and checking if the last file has been moved?

Comment: @LetzerWille: When each `shutil.move` completes, that move is *done*. When `move_files_while_script_waits` returns, *all* moves are *done*. There's nothing to wait for (the calls don't return until the work is complete), unless you've got some threads in your program you haven't mentioned (in which case, join the moving thread in the thread that's waiting for it to finish, or coordinate by some interthread synchronization primitive like an `Event`).